# Macbook Late 2011. Swapped HDD for SDD. Now I have read-only access

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, ssd, permission, carbon-copy-cloner

I have a MacBook late 2011 and some time ago I replaced the HDD with a SSD for a Windows partition. The HDD with macOS went to the place where the CD Drive was. I had this configuration for some months.
Now I wanted to swap the macOS HDD with an SSD too. The SSD I've got is a Samsung 860 EVO.

I made a copy of my current macOS system from the HDD to the SSD via USB using Carbon Copy Cloner. Then I installed the SSD in the MacBook.

The system now starts very quickly. But it seems the whole SSD is read-only! I can't even create a new folder on the SSD. I always get *Error -50*. All programs that want to write files do not work. Dropbox even tells me that there are problems with the permissions. Disk Utility's First Aid does not find any problems. I tried to fix the permissions but I get the message that I have no ownership of the SSD. I have not been able to get ownership because it seems to need root privileges. But I can't activate a root user, because I can't write to the SSD.

Now I have connected the formerly internal HDD via USB and booted from that. I can't write to the SSD either.

I had the same problem before. I had just tried a different SSD before. The same behavior. There I tried to reinstall with the System recovery on the SSD but the process always aborted with the message that the SSD was damaged. When I put the HDD back in the machine everything was fine. So I guess it is no problem with the connectors or wiring.

I can only imagine that the hardware somehow does not support this. But the other SSD in the machine is the exact same type.

Comment: Have you tried to log in as an administrator and get the file info and set admin to full access?

Comment: [Do a clean install and don't clone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310415/119271) when going from a HDD to SSD.  I'm not a user of CCC (don't like it, don't see a need for it) but I'm guessing you made a *backup* and not a clone.  It's more of a config issue and not something to do with your drives or wiring.

Comment: Also, do you have backups of your data and/or files *other* than what you've copied or made clones of?

Comment: I have always done a drive replacement by *first* putting the replacement drive in the Mac, then putting the old drive in a USB enclosure and booting from that. Once the new drive is installed you can then format the new drive and clone the old to the new. That way the new drive is already in place and working and you are cloning your current data to the new drive.

Comment: For me, it was having data in the cloud, on a Time Machine backup and a duplicate of my Users folder  - 3 places.  Then with new drive in place, boot from USB installer or from Internet Recovery so I started with the cleanest possible install.  Since I don't use more than 256GB on any machine, I'm thinking my very next Mac, I'm going to partition the drive in half so that when I upgrade, I leave my working partition in place, and install on the other.  Next update, same thing but swap partitions...